# How do I add .java/.class files to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I know how to add .java/class files to a certain project, or import them into a package. So, when you're using eclipse you can import java.awt.*; and java.util.*; and the but those are all packages inside the JRE. So my real question is: is there any way to import a package containing the files i want into the JRE so that, if i create a new project, I can simply import them whenever I need them? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't place your classes into jre classes, you should pack them in a JAR (Java Archive) and then distribute it, and let the client add it to its classpath so they can import it

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Generally, you have more then one choice. You can link the project(s) in eclipse, and then have project B with a reference to project A. Or, you can create a build artifact like a jar file and add it to the project B build/run path. Simply add a jar file to your project, right click and select *Add to Build Path*. Another alternative is to use a build tool that manages dependencies like [gradle](https://gradle.org/), [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/), [maven](https://maven.apache.org/), or [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Note that there are a wide variety of third-party opensource libraries you can add as dependencies using these (and other) tools.

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure if it makes a difference. The classes that I need my current project to use are in a folder i downloaded from the internet. Should i just put all of those projects in eclipse and then make them a jar?

Comment: A jar file is just a zipfile with some extra metadata. And no, you need the original folder structure too.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to create a shared library, which in Java is a `.jar` file. The steps to do this in Eclipse are:

> In the Package Explorer, you can optionally pre-select one or more Java elements to export. (These will be automatically selected in the Opens the JAR export wizard JAR Package Specification wizard page, described in Step 4.)
>
> Either from the context menu or from the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
>
> Expand the Java node and select JAR file. Click Next.
>
> In the JAR File Specification page, select the resources that you want to export in the Select the resources to export field.
>
> Select the appropriate checkbox to specify whether you want to Export generated class files and resources or Export Java source files and resources. Note: Selected resources are exported in both cases.
>
> In the Select the export destination field, either type or click Browse to select a location for the JAR file.
>
> Select or clear the Compress the contents of the JAR file checkbox.
>
> Select or clear the Overwrite existing files without warning checkbox. If you clear this checkbox, then you will be prompted to confirm the replacement of each file that will be overwritten.
>
> Note: The overwrite option is applied when writing the JAR file, the JAR description, and the manifest file.
>
> You have two options:
>           Click Finish to create the JAR file immediately.
>           Click Next to use the JAR Packaging Options page to set advanced options, create a JAR description, or change the default manifest.

Credit goes to [the docs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm).

Comment: Hey! thanks for your input. As I'm going through the steps I think (and I could very well be mistaken) that I should clarify. I downloaded a folder containing many .java and .class files. I want to have access to those files, without having to take those classes and put them inside the package I'm using. It seems as though above I am going to end up putting the project I'm creating in a java file and allowing that to be accessed in other projects that I may do in the future?